# SwiftUI: How can I change the color of the button when the button is clicked?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have some buttons that has circle padding around them and I want to switch the color from green to red when the user clicks on the button.

More specifically, the button should be green if `ExcludedNumbers` does not contain 1 and it should be red when `ExcludedNumbers` contains 1.

**My code:**

```
var ExcludedNumbers = Set([0])

 Button("1") {
       if ExcludedNumbers.contains(1) == false {
            ExcludedNumbers.insert(1)
            print(ExcludedNumbers)
        } else if ExcludedNumbers.contains(1) == true {
            ExcludedNumbers.remove(1)
            print(ExcludedNumbers)
        }
 }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 20, bottom: 10, trailing: 20))
  .background(.green)
  .clipShape(Circle())
```

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to be related to what you mention in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace your `background` modifier with:

```
.background(ExcludedNumbers.contains(1) ? .red: .green)
```

Also make sure that ExcludedNumbers is a `@State` variable:

```
@State var ExcludedNumbers = Set([0])
```

Quick notes:

- property names should start with lowercased letters. `class, struct, enum...` names should start with capital letters.
- `if ExcludedNumbers.contains(1) == true` can be replaced with `if ExcludedNumbers.contains(1)`. Similarly, `if ExcludedNumbers.contains(1) == false` can be replaced with `if !ExcludedNumbers.contains(1)`